# Subclass UItableViewCell with multiple Legends and Labels

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, interface-builder

I Know this question has been asked *a lot* in a hundred different ways (and thats just on this site).  But I'm struggling to put all the pieces together.

I would like **each `UITableViewCell`** to look like this:

[image]

It has multple legends and several fields.  The legends are static and wont change but the corressponding labels will vary in width and height.   Therefore so will the cells. I need the legends to always align with their labels.

I have tried to do this using the `Interface Builder` but don't really understand the autoresizing.  Though I'm happy to do this in code.

Does anybody know how to do this or at least have some good links to tutorials, source code etc?

Comment: Wait so is that picture your table or is that supposed to be one cell?

Comment: Just one cell. Each cell represents an event in a list of events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting a full table view inside a cell is ***crazytalk***. Maybe somebody got it to actually run - that doesn't mean it's best practice or good practice.

I will answer your question after making one very down to earth suggestion. Please consider following Apple's guidelines by putting just a summary of each event in your cells for this table, and allow the user to push down to another view controller to see the details of a particular event. This will probably help you develop your app faster and get to market, then you can think about advanced stuff like customizing individual cell heights at runtime.

That being said, if you insist on putting all your eggs in this basket, then I think you will need to implement your table view cell in IB, note the details for all of your content label frame dimensions, then, at run time, use one of NSString's `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:` methods to determine how big your labels will be. Make them that big. Then from that data compute the height of your cell, and return that value from your table view's `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`. This is how I implemented this functionality in an app a few years back. (Frankly I'm not sure that it's still working.) There may be some better methods for figuring out the label size in CoreText, I haven't looked.

A better bet will be to constrain yourself to a limit on the length of text you can put in each label. Then you can just define the labels statically and use a constant-sized cell. Putting it together in IB isn't tough. Just lay everything out, and make sure that you create an IBOutlet and XCode/IB connection for each object you want to manipulate in code.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Add a tableview to each UITableViewCell. The outer tableView will be responsible for holding all your cells and each cell will be a Event with cells for each parameter.

This tutorial will give you insight on how to set that up.

http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/adding-a-uitableview-inside-a-uitableviewcell/